# OpenCV cv::Mat::forEach() method race condition

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv, race-condition

I have the following code, where I am trying to utilize the multithreaded access to elements of an OpenCV `cv::Mat` class using the `forEach()` member method. But when I run this code in `valgrind --tool=helgrind` I get multiple race condition reports. Also it doesn't work as intended, i.e., mask the image with another image. What is the reason for this behavior?

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  cv::Mat1f im(21, 21, 0.0f);
  im(cv::Rect(7, 7, 7, 7)) = 0.5;
  cv::Mat1b mask(21, 21, 0.0);
  mask(cv::Rect(9, 9, 3, 3)) = 1;
  cv::Mat1f result(21, 21, 0.0f);
  mask.forEach([&result, &im] (uchar val, const int* pos)
  {
    if (val == 0)
      result(pos[1], pos[0]) = 0;
    else
      result(pos[1], pos[0]) = im(pos[1], pos[0]);
  });
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work as intended"? It does exactly the same thing as a simple `im.copyTo(result, mask);` does. What do you expect it to do?

Comment: I'm not interested in a simpler way, just trying to understand why this code results in race conditions.

Comment: I'm simply explaining what it does by comparing it with an existing function. You claim that "it doesn't work as intended", yet for some reason you choose to ignore the questions for clarification and post that instead. | As for the race condition, I don't really see any. Internally `forEach` uses parallel_for_ and splits it by rows. Does helgrind produce some details you could share?